# Angular 2: Is it a good practice to store component specific data in a shared service?

Tags: angular

Currently, I have an array of integers in my component class.
The template iterates over this array and displays its data.

This array of data is required by other components too.

Is it good practice to store this array in a service as a multi-dimensional array so that other component classes can use it?
(multi-dimensional because multiple instances of a component may be present)

Answer (score 1):

Shared Services are used to shared data among components. But,

> **Beware of refreshing the application. If you refresh the page, You will lose data shared using shared service**.

So, you have to use other mechanism to store data (with shared service). eg. **HTML5 Storage**.

Comment: that is fine I think, same is applicable for data stored in component right?

Comment: Note sure. But I guess not same with component.

Answer (score 0):

In general, yes, services are used to share data between components.
What you could consider is creating an rxjs `Subject` in your shared service.

This way, components could `subscribe` to that Subject (Observable) and automatically receive the latest value.

You could then leverage Angular 2's `async` pipe and have Angular 2 subscribe to these Observables by itself.

More on `async` pipe: http://briantroncone.com/?p=623

More on rxjs Subjects: http://reactivex.io/rxjs/manual/overview.html#subject

Also, depending on your knowledge of redux, I suggest you check out `ngrx/store` which helps you manage state across your whole application.

https://github.com/ngrx/store